Vertical scroll bar in browser bookmarks folder
This issue in presented in several browsers I tested (Brave, Chrome, Vivaldi, Opera)...
My box have Ubuntu 22.04.4.
I have certain bookmarks folders with several bookmarks on them. It is annoying that there is no dropdown buttons neither vertical scroll bar. Having to use a scroll mouse wheel to slowly go down to where I need to find something specific is tiresome.
Is there a way to implement a vertical scroll bar to make it faster?

It seems to be a browser issue not the OS.

@David all of them decided to remove the vertical scroll bar?
